# Changing _id in MongoDb

Tags: php, mongodb

just curious - I've got a bunch of records in a MongoDB collection that have _id set to something that was defined outside Mongo (They are the ID's the data had when it was in MySQL, and the were imported with _id being set to the MySQL ID). What would be the best way (preferably with PHP) to convert those ID's to something Mongo generated?

So instead of a record having _id = 500, it would have an _id = 53fcf8d6c4d3f7df129e3245.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not update the `_id` so the only way will be to retrieve all documents from the database and insert them either with a new _id you generated yourself [(documentation here)](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongoid.php) or without an `_id` field so (pseudocode because I don't know the php driver):

```
 for (i=0;i<max_mysql_id;i++){
     doc = db.find({_id:i},{_id :0}); //Select document without the _id field
     db.insert(doc);
     db.remove({_id:i});
 }
```

assuming you know the `_id`s you inserted.